# Getting PDFTK installed on heroku Cedar Stack for use in my app

Tags: heroku, pdftk, buildpack

so I have building management app, which locally uses the pdftk to generate pdf forms (prefilled with tenant/expense data). Works like magic on my local machine.
However, on Heroku I get the error:

pdftk executable /usr/local/bin/pdftk not found

in the logs when I try to generate the pdf file. I realize that I need to install pdftk on my heroku app using a buildpack. I've tried following some tutorials with Vulcan, but vulcan is deprecated and they say use heroku run, however I can't find much documentation of how to install the pdftk-source: https://github.com/millie/pdftk-source using heroku run.

I'm going to try https://github.com/millie/heroku-buildpack-ruby-pdftk, but if there is an easier/less messy way let me know, thanks!

EDIT:
Tried the above method, and now my heroku logs say: 
RuntimeError (pdftk executable /app/vendor/pdftk/bin not found)
So I'm thinking the buildpack didn't include pdftk to begin with, which doesn't make sense.
I must be doing something wrong, but I followed the instructions exactly, only difference is I used dropbox instead of S3 to store the tar.gz file (the pdftk source)

EDIT:
OK, I figured out how to include pdftk executable in the heroku buildpack and upload it successfully as part of the app environment. HOWEVER, for some very strange reason, in the heroku bash console, when I cd into pdftk directory and try to run the executable, heroku bash says pdftk executable not found.

It works on my local machine, when cd into the pdftk directory and run pdftk, it runs the executable, so its not the executable..so why isn't it working inside the heroku bash directory?

SOLUTION:
Was missing setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my config vars on heroku, because pdftk relies on a library file. Also, remember to tar the tar.gz to the root directory and set a PATH to /bin/pdftk. Just check out #heroku on IRC, that's where I got my answer.

Comment: PdfTk is nothing more than iText compiled with the GNU Compiler for Java (GCJ). Why would you introduce a call to an executable in your code when you can use iText directly from code without having to depend on an external executable?

Comment: itext requires jruby or rjb it seems, so does pdfstamper, I'd prefer not to use those, as they add errors into my app in some places..all I really want to do is call the pdftk executable from within my app at app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk. It works, if the path is /user/local/bin/pdftk but not app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk, here he got it to work: http://micahroberson.com/generating-pdfs-from-templates-in-ruby-on-rails-and-heroku/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was missing setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my config vars on heroku, because pdftk relies on a library file. Also, remember to tar the tar.gz to the root directory and set a PATH to `/bin/pdftk`. Just check out #heroku on IRC, that's where I got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i setup pdftk in nodejs app in heroku

1. Create heroku app

   ```
   heroku create
   ```
2. Set buildpack for pdftk

   ```
   BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
   ```
3. Set buildpack for nodejs

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```
4. Add the libgcj.so.* to your search path:

   ```
   heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/bin
   ```
5. Turn on at least one dyno

   ```
   heroku ps:scale web=1
   ```
6. Create a Procfile in the root of your project and define the following:

   ```
   web: node server.js
   ```
7. Push changes in heroku

   ```
   git push heroku master
   ```

Comment: This answer no longer works, the build pack quits after showing a deprecation warning

Answer (score 0):

## Adding answer that worked as of July 2019

*Note: Thanks to [shake-apps](https://github.com/shake-apps) for creating the Buildpack https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/shake-apps/heroku-buildpack-pdftk*

If you need to have PDFtk installed on Heroku for a Node JS Application, follow these instructions:

### Heroku Installation

You'll need to set the base `nodejs` buildpack, and the `pdftk` buildpack by `shake-apps`.

Set them by running the following:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs;
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/shake-apps/heroku-buildpack-pdftk.git;
```

After build packs are set, the server can be deployed normally with

```
git push heroku master
```

---

If you have any issues with the deploy it could be your previous buildpack. You can clear it to start fresh with:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

Comment: Does adding the buildpack through the heroku dashboard settings work the same way? I'm not getting any errors, but the module I'm using (pdffiller) doesn't do anything or at least doesn't do what it's intended to do.